# cordova-plugin-datecs-printer

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, escpos

I'm trying to use a termic printer Leopardo A7, and I need to print an image and a text. I already printed an image and a text, but I can't print both side by side... can anybody help me ?

I'm using:
window.DatecsPrinter.printText() to print text...
and 
window.DatecsPrinter.printImage() to print images...,

but how can I print text and images side by side ??

Comment: Is this with an ionic project?

Comment: Yes, a project on a internship. One year ago...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using page mode. You'll need to set page mode and define page region.

Check the methods `selectPageMode`, `setPageRegion` and `printPage`.